# Reading the whole file and then outputting the lines with a certain order

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader

i'm working on a function which reads a file of strings with n lines.

Imagine each line in the file is numbered, starting from 0. i m trying to modify this function so it reads the whole file and then outputs the lines numbered 0, 3, 6,...

followed by the lines numbered 1, 4, 7,.... and finally followed by the lines numbered 2, 5, 8,....

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {

    String s;

    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();

    while((s = r.readLine())!=null){
        tmp.add(s);
    }


    for (String text : s) {
        w.println(text);
    }
}
```

like for example:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

should output

```
0
3
6
9
1
4
7
2
5
8
```

i'm sure i need to use the % sign. but i cant seem to figure out how. any help will be appreciated

Comment: The brute force option here is to just read the entire file with each line as an entry in an array, and then iterate over this array.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `List<Integer>` if you store only int value (with `Integer.parseInt(s)` and catch the `NumberFormatException`).

Then you have to sort your List (with `Collections.sort()`) like this :

```
    Collections.sort(tmp, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return new Integer(o1 % 3).compareTo(new Integer(o2 % 3));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this loop to achieve what you want after you have created the list:

```
    int gap = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < gap; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < tmp.size(); j+=gap) {
            System.out.println(tmp.get(j));
        }
    }
```

If you want to jump more than 3, you just update the variable gap.

Answer (score 1):

For this example will be taken into account that has all its lines in an array of strings, here I present a recursive function that iterates threes in the loop

```
static int cont=0;
public static int ReadLines(String[]array,int init)
{
  if(cont>array.length-1)return 0;
  else
  {
    for (int i = init; i < array.length; i+=3) {
          System.out.println(array[i]);
          cont++;
      }
    return ReadLines(array, init+1);
  }
}
```

Call the function

```
String[] array = new String[]{"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
ReadLines(array,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the file to 3 lists and then write one list after the other to the output:

```
final int num = 3;
ArrayList<String>[] lists = new ArrayList[num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    lists[i] = new ArrayList<>();
}

String s;
for (int i = 0; (s = r.readLine())!=null; i++) {
    lists[i % num].add(s);
}

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (String line : lists[i]) {
        w.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the lines to a array or list and you can get them by the index

Comment: This is already the case. `tmp` is a `List`, and the lines of the file are added to it. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39544076/6746785) answer for the index you said.